# how to set interval in order to display images by turn

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

so... i get an image from the array, the problem with setting the time interval,in order to display images by turn

```
$(function() {
    var length = $('.fadein img').length; //get the number of images
    var arrayimage = [];
    for (i=0; i<length; i++){ // fill the array
        arrayimage.push($(".fadein img:eq("+ i +")").attr("src"));  
    }
    var lengtharray = arrayimage.length;
    setTimeout(function run() { 
        for (i=0; i<lengtharray; i++){ //get images by turn
            var cft = arrayimage[i];               
            var imageurl = cft;
            $("html").css({
                'background': '#000000 url("' +imageurl + '") no-repeat top left fixed',
                'background-size' : 'cover', 
                'width':'100%',
                'height':'100%',
                'position':'avsolute'
            });  
           setTimeout(cft, 5000);
            alert("set");
        }
        },5000);

});
```

How to set interval? 
It's html code if necessary :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery2.0.3.js"></script>        
        <script src="js/jquery/slideshow.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fadein">
            <img src="images/backgrounds/stones.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/backgrounds/pier.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/backgrounds/sea-mist.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/backgrounds/mojave.jpg"/>
            <img src="images/backgrounds/flowing-rock.jpg"/>
        </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: position:avsolute; will never work, try position:absolute;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
setTimeout(cft, 5000);
```

'cft' is a string. You should be passing setTimeout a function. You have to think of setTimeout in terms of a reusable function that repeats. You execute that function in your first outer setTimeout and then that function calls itself internally in subsequent setTimeouts. If you want it to kick off right away the first call will be straight to your function instead of in a setTimeout.

What is the slideshow plugin you are using? You may find some of the answers you seek in it's documentation.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking:

```
$(function() {

    //set up
    $('.fadein img').hide().eq(0).addClass('nextup');

    rotate = function(){
        var imageurl = $('.fadein img.nextup').attr('src')
        //next
        $('.fadein img.nextup').removeClass('nextup').next('img').addClass('nextup');
        if($('.fadein img.nextup').length == 0){
            //back to first
            $('.fadein img').hide().eq(0).addClass('nextup');
        }
        $("html").css({
            'background': '#000000 url("' +imageurl + '") no-repeat top left fixed',
            'background-size' : 'cover',
            'width':'100%',
            'height':'100%',
            'position':'absolute'
        });
        setTimeout(rotate, 5000);
    };
    rotate();
});
```

Comment: i am not using plugin. i understand but How to implement it?

Comment: Your html references: <script src="js/jquery/slideshow.js"></script>
Is that not used?

Comment: I mean that I am not using ready plugins. <script src="js/jquery/slideshow.js"></script> this is my page for slides

Comment: it working=) please, explain to me this. 
we hide the first picture and add to the class'nextup', then begin to function rotate, for the variable imageurl, we set src current image which is in the class 'nextup'. then remove this image from the class and add the folowing image. 
Did i understand you correctly?
$('.fadein img').hide().eq(0).addClass('nextup'); what do this line? and why we are writing rotate() at the end?  };
    rotate();
});
if not difficult to explain to me =)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, instead of `setTimeout`, you want [`setInterval(function, milliseconds)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).